# OpenMP undefined reference to `_CRT_fenv' and `_setargv'

Tags: c++, mingw, openmp, undefined-reference

I'm trying to run this simple OpenMP example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    switch(_OPENMP) {
    case 200805:
        cout << "OpenMP version 3.0 has macro value of 200805" << endl;
        break;
    case 200505:
        cout << "OpenMP version 2.5 has macro value of 200505" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Unrecognized OpenMP version of " << _OPENMP << endl;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get two `undefined reference to` errors :

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `_CRT_fenv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x1fb): undefined reference to `_setargv'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already added `libgomp-1.dll` to link librairies and `-fopenmp` to other compiler options ( I'm working with code::blocks by the way ).

Comment: Are you using minGW?
Please mention platform, OS, IDE, compiler you are using in your question to make it easier for people to focus on the issue instead to making them guess for you.

Comment: @GauravPathak yes

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with minGW environment. I compiled your code on Linux and it compiled without any error and ran perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Stoufa Have you searched the error on Google?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro, Code::Blocks 16.01, MinGW
@GauravPathak of course I did ! that's why I posted my question here

Comment: Just fix it by moving the MinGW folder from C:\ to Code::Blocks' folder and changing compiler's installation directory !
Strange ! why it didn't work when the folder was under C:\ ?!!! it was a recommendation to install it in a path without spaces !
However, thank you.

Comment: @Stoufa: That sounds like bad advice. "I'm too tall for this car" - "we can chop off your head".

Comment: @Olaf it was a recommendation from MinGW !

Comment: @Stoufa: That does not make it any better. But Windows ppl are used to dirty workarounds, I suppose …

Comment: @Olaf using windows wasn't my choice ;) so relax !

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I had the same errors and found this post in my search for an answer, so I suspect I may be able to help someone else with this problem.

I suspect the problem lies in having two installations of MinGW.  Did you install the full distribution of Code::Blocks, including MinGw?

The errors reference "c:/mingw/..."  I am guessing that you did a separate installation of MinGW, which created that tree.  If you let Code::Blocks install it, too, it probably put it in "*some_path*/CodeBlocks/MinGW/."

If that is the case (as it was for me), in Code::Blocks, go to Settings->Compiler... and in the window that opens, open the "Toolchain executables" tab and change the path for your MinGW executables to be the insatllation path created by Code::Blocks.
[image]

Comment: Hey @Bob, thanks for posting. umm, I don't remember, it has been some time since the last time I've used Windows, I used it during university (wasn't my choice), I'm a free man now, however, I hope that this thread will help someone facing the same issue, thanks again. 

Comment: "I suspect the problem lies in having two installations of MinGW." - This was exactly the problem in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Bob said,the reason is there are two installations of MinGW.After I uninstall the former installed version,cFree works.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35205300)